# Angular Directive show and hide div within template

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, angular-directive-link

I have created a directive that I use on an attribute, in particular a button or anchor.

When clicking the button I append a template (that contains a div) after the button.  If the button (or outside of the button / menu ie. body) is clicked again I would like to hide the div contained in the template.

I have the following so far but I can't get the isVisible to update and hide the div (menu)

Main directive code:

```
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            scope.isVisible = false;

            element.bind('click', function () {

                var menu = element.parent().find('.actionMenuDir');

                if (menu.length === 0) {

                    $templateRequest('app/directives/popupmenu/actionpopup.html').then(function(html) {
                        var template = angular.element(html);
                        element.after(template);
                        $compile(template)(scope);
                    });

                } else {
                    scope.isVisible = !scope.isVisible;
                }

                $compile(menu)(scope);

            });

        }

    }
```

Template markup:

```
<div class="actionMenuDir" ng-if="isVisible">
{{isVisible}}
<ul>
    <li>Menu Yo</li>
</ul>
```

Button markup with directive used:

```
<button popup-menu type="button">BUTTON</button>
```

Comment: You know, you can use `ng-if` for adding-removing elements based on a scope variable.

Comment: Yes, and if you read my question properly you will see I'm trying to use that :)

Comment: I assume your directive code is for `popup-menu`?

Comment: It is, I've already used the Bootstrap one and it's not flexible enough.